# how to get C++ GDI code into a C# project

Tags: c#, c++, gdi

I have 2 projects a C# project that has most everything that I need and a GDI C++ project that has a control and some logic I want to put into the C# project.

Do I wrap the GDI C++ project somehow as a control? Is there some newer technology that I should update the GDI code to use (not sure how GDI is different than GDI+).

Just getting started looking at this and have no idea how to integrate the two.

Comment: You don't know enough yet to ask a meaningful question.  That C++ code uses GDI to implement painting is an irrelevant detail, much more important is how it exposes its capabilities to other code.  There is more than one way to do this, like RegisterWindowEx() or ActiveX, that is what you need to focus on first.

Comment: Hans, so I would create a dll from the c++ code, that has a com interface (actives or registerWindowx)? And then import that dll into my C# project to use?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use COM, you could integrate both using C++/CLI or P/Invoke for instance. But the best way to do it depends on how the C++ code exposes its functionality like Hans said, so we need more details to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the complexity of your c++ code.

if it's large or complex then it'd be best to wrap it and use it from the c# (e.g. wrap it in a COM wrapper, or even run it as a separate process that simply displays its window in your host.

If it's not too complex then it is likely to be easier and cleaner to port it to c#. A lot of c++ code for logic is easy to port to c#, and there is very little difference between GDI and GDI+, so I would expect porting to be fairly straight forward.

The deciding factor might just be your own confidence in using com or getting GDI+ to render the same thing.